# Set selected option value using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework

I am using drop-down in PHP. How to set the selected value after POST method. I create the select box in php file. Below i mentioned sample code

```
<?php 
  $postval = $_POST['dbfld'];

  $opvar = "<select name='".$name."' id='".$Id."'><option    value=''> Select ART_ID</option>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    $opvar .= "<option value='".$row[$dbfld]."'>".$row[$dbfld]."</option>";
  }

  $opvar .= "</select>";
?>
```

In the above example, How i set selected option after the post method.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
  $postval = $_POST['dbfld'];

  $opvar = "<select name='".$name."' id='".$Id."'><option    value=''> Select ART_ID</option>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    $selected = $postval == $row[$dbfld] ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    $opvar .= "<option value='".$row[$dbfld]."'".$selected.">".$row[$dbfld]."</option>";
  }

  $opvar .= "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake you could also do this with a simple if clause.

```
if($postval == $row[$dbfld]){
   $opvar .= "<option value='".$row[$dbfld]."' selected='selected'>".$row[$dbfld]."</option>";
}else{
   $opvar .= "<option value='".$row[$dbfld]."'>".$row[$dbfld]."</option>";
}
```

While this does add a chunk of code for some simple functionality, it will allow you to do more extensive actions in the if clause without having to add further code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the property `selected="selected"` of `<select>` element.

Use ternary operator for minimizing code.

```
<?php 
$postval = $_POST['dbfld'];    
$opvar = "<select name='".$name."' id='".$Id."'><option    value=''> Select ART_ID</option>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
  $selected = ($row[$dbfld] == $postval) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
  $opvar .= "<option value='".$row[$dbfld]."'" . $selected . ">".$row[$dbfld]."</option>";
}
$opvar .= "</select>";
?>
```